# Firebase onDisconnect().set() with function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have to do some stuff when Firebase disconnects and also call a `set()`:

```js
this.state.ref.child('users/' + uid + '/online').onDisconnect().set(false, function(){

          // ... do some stuff ...

        })
```

But it seems like the function inside `set()` calls regardless whether of connection is disconnected.

How to call a function in `onDisconnect().set()` properly?

Comment: What do you expect this function to do? And when do you expect it to be called?

Comment: I expect that function will be called when disconnection from Firebase occurs. My function should stop all setInterval() functions.

Comment: In that case my answer is what you're looking for. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `onDisconnect()` you are sending a *value* to the database server now, that the database will then set once it detects that the client that set this value disappeared. You can't run code in an `onDisconnect` handler, because the handler runs on the server.

If you want to run code on the client when it is disconnected from the server, you can listen to the `.info/connected` value in the tree. For an example of this, see the Firebase documentation on [detecting connection state](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state).

You'll typically combine `onDisconnect` handlers and  `.info/connected` listeners to implement full offline behavior for your app.

Comment: Could you please clarify how did you see combining ```onDisconnect``` handlers and ```.info/connected``` listeners?

Comment: @puf Can we use this to check Internet Connectivity (given my app is connected to rtdb all the time)? Currently am using `navigator.onLine` event listener - but it only responds if the device is connected to any network (not necessarily Internet).

Comment: All of those do different things: `navigator.onLine` detects network, `.info/connected` detects a connection to Firebase Realtime Database. You should use the detection method that most closely matches with what you want to show to your users.